# Assignment Branch Condition for install_package is too high

Tags: ruby

This is my first time using Ruby and I am running Rubocop to check my code and keep getting the warning `Assignment Branch Condition for install_package is too high`. I have had a look at some questions tackling this issue, but I am a bit unsure about how to tackle the issue in my situation. I would appreciate any advice:

```
def install_package
    node.run_state['fullList'].each do |p|
        rpm_package p do
            source "#{node.run_state['repo]}/#{p}"
            options "--prefix #{node['sw']['swclient']['install_path']}/#{node.run_state['sw_inst_path']}"
            action :install
            only_if { node.run_state['failureCount'].zero? }
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: My preferred solution for ABC complaints is to disable that cop in my config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you'll need to know what Assignment Branch Condition is before we can tackle this issue:

When looking at the [default config](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop/blob/5d47450b8e0cfff61da08b94c656bec26407fd8a/config/default.yml#L1827-L1841) file we see that the default max value is 15, and that references to http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?AbcMetric and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABC_Software_Metric are given.

Let's first have a look at the references. The first link says the following:

> - Assignment -- an explicit transfer of data into a variable, e.g. = *= /= %= += <<= >>= &= |= ^= >>>= ++ --
> - Branch -- an explicit forward program branch out of scope -- a function call, class method call, or new operator
> - Condition -- a logical/Boolean test, == != <= >= < > else case default try catch ? and unary conditionals.
>
> A scalar ABC size value (or "aggregate magnitude") is computed as:
>
> ```
> |ABC| = sqrt((A*A)+(B*B)+(C*C))
> ```

Summarized: Assignment count increases when you assign something to a variable. Branch count increases when you call a method or function. Condition count increases when doing comparisons like `1 > 2`.

Applying this to your code we can see that this results in the following number:

```
def install_package
  node.run_state['fullList'].each do |p|
  # ^B ^B       ^B           ^B

    rpm_package p do
    # ^B
      source "#{node.run_state['repo']}/#{p}"
      # ^B      ^B   ^B       ^B
      options "--prefix #{node['sw']['swclient']['install_path']}/#{node.run_state['sw_inst_path']}"
      # ^B                ^B  ^B    ^B          ^B                  ^B   ^B       ^B
      action :install
      # ^B
      only_if { node.run_state['failureCount'].zero? }
      # ^B      ^B   ^B       ^B               ^B
    end
  end
end
```

Resulting in an ABC size of:

```
Math.sqrt(0**2 + 23**2 + 0**2) #=> 23
```

Let me start of by saying that the default max ABC-size is quite low. And you might want to up this in your [RuboCop config](https://docs.rubocop.org/en/stable/configuration/) or disable the setting all together. Now let's have a look at how to resolve this.

Most of the time when ABC-size is an issue it means you've got too much complexity in you method. The easiest way to resolve this is to create helper methods and extract complexity from your main method.

Another option is to assign method return values to a variable. that way you cache the return value. For example you call the `node` method 5 times. You could save the method result in a variable and use that instead. `node = self.node` This way you replace 5 branches with 1 branch and 1 assignment.

I've worked out an example solution that extracts complexity from the `install_package` method, this answer assumes that the code is placed in class or module context (otherwise the `private` doesn't make sense).

```
def install_packages # ABC-size Math.sqrt(0**2 + 12**2 + 1**2) #=> 12.041...
  node.run_state['fullList'].each do |package|
  # ^B ^B       ^B           ^B
    rpm_package package do
    # ^B
      source package_source(package)
      # ^B   ^B
      options "--prefix #{install_path}"
      # ^B                ^B
      action :install
      # ^B
      only_if { !failures? }
      # ^B      ^C ^B
    end
  end
end

private

def package_source(package) # ABC-size Math.sqrt(0**2 + 3**2 + 0**2) #=> 3
  "#{node.run_state['repo']}/#{package}"
  #  ^B   ^B       ^B
end

def install_path # ABC-size Math.sqrt(2**2 + 7**2 + 0**2) #=> 7.280...
  root_install_path = node['sw']['swclient']['install_path']
  #                 ^A ^B ^B    ^B          ^B
  relative_install_path = node.run_state['sw_inst_path']
  #                     ^A ^B  ^B       ^B
  "#{root_install_path}/#{relative_install_path}"
end

def failures? # ABC-size Math.sqrt(0**2 + 4**2 + 0**2) #=> 4
  node.run_state['failureCount'].positive?
  # ^B ^B       ^B               ^B
end
```

**Note:** I'm not entirely sure if the exclamation mark in `!value` counts towards branches or conditions. For the sake of the examples I've counted them towards conditionals.

Comment: You might be wondering why `value['string']` counts towards branches. If so, let me quickly explain. `[]` is a method on `value` and could also be written as `value.[]('string')` therefore it counts as a branch. The same applies for a lot of operators. For example `1 + 1` can also be written as `1.+(1)`. Like you can see `+` is also a method and therefore also counts towards branches.